# Rails 3.1 Submit form without refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a form here on my `orders/_form.html.erb` that I want to submit and save in a table called Categories

```
<%= simple_form_for(@category) do |f| %>

  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">

    <%= f.input :name, 

:label => false, 

:input_html => { :class => 'text', 

:style => 'float:left; width:250px' }, 

:placeholder => "Type of item / name of expense",


%>



   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, 

:value => current_user.id %>


   <%= f.button :submit, 

:value => 'Add Category', 

:class => 'small grey',

:style => 'margin:5px 0 0 10px' %>


  </div>



<% end %>
```

In my categories_controller.rb I have this code to create the category:

```
# POST /categories

  # POST /categories.json

  def create

    @category = current_user.categories.build(params[:category])



    respond_to do |format|

      if @category.save

        format.html { redirect_to new_order_path }

        format.json { render json: new_order_path, status: :created, location: @category }

      else

        format.html { render action: "new" }

        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

      end

    end

  end
```

First, how do I make it so that when you submit the form, it doesn't refresh the page?   Then I want the Categories dropdown http://d.pr/gUwz to have the new entry in there as well (I assume using JQ).  Any idea how to get me started with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Rails 3.x you have to use `:remote => true` with form

Ex:

```
<%= form_for @comment, :remote => true, :html => { :'data-type' => 'html', :id => 
 <form code>
<% end %>
```

and make sure you include jQuery js files.

Comment: Ok, so I put that in the simple_form...how does the new content appear then on that page after submitting?

Comment: Also, after the form is submitted, how do I make it so that people don't click it a million times?

Answer (score 1):

You shold send a ajax request in the form tag using:

> :remote => true

Check the docs about for_for method: [FormHelper#form_for-instance_method](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper#form_for-instance_method)

Since JQuery is default to rails 3.0 you should have no problems doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use :remote => true in form tag, this will submit form as with ajax request and form will get submitted without refreshing page.